# Xamarin iOS Binding - Protocol - Cannot Create Instance of Abstract Class

Tags: xamarin.ios, protocols, abstract-class, objective-sharpie

I've generated some binding code using Sharpie for the Zebra Scanner SDK.

[Zebra Scanner SDK](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/scanner-sdk-for-iOS.html)

The generated code builds fine once I've processed the `[Verify]` attributes.

The starting point for the SDK is to call a static method on the SDK factory which then should return the SDK Api object.  The create SDK Api method is bound to a native call which I can't manipulate.

The SDK Api object is a protocol and the code generated by Sharpie is an abstract class.

So when trying to create the SDK Api object, as instructed through the API factory, I get a runtime exception `Cannot create instance of an abstract class`.

I'm a bit lost as to how to resolve this.  Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read this document about [protocols-with-xamarinios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/delegates-protocols-and-events#protocols-with-xamarinios).

> Any class can provide annotation data by simply deriving from
>   MKAnnotation, as long as at least the Coordinate property is
>   implemented.

Just create a new class that inherits from `SDK Api objec` and then initialize it with your data there.

Comment: Thanks.  It wasn't quite that simple but your suggestion led me to the solution.  The automated code generation couldn't figure out the SDK implementation and I had to import and modify the automated binding code.